# Triggering a C# function using Arduino input

Tags: c#, arduino

I am using C#, Visual Studio and Arduino. My overall system is bit complex. But here I want to know a simple thing I think. I want to trigger a C# function when a certain pin in arduino UNO is getting HIGH.That means I want to take a input to the visual studio system from arduino and run the function.

I tried below code which was found from internet. But I can not use it properly. I tried more various methods in u tube to. But all were failed.

Also want to tell I am developing a firmware system of a RFID reader. So there are so many classes and functions. And also the reading function of the reader is continuously running running and i want to use this trigger to stop that function and close the application.

```
  using System;
    using System.IO.Ports;

    class PortDataReceived
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
            mySerialPort.Close();
        }

        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                            object sender,
                            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
            Console.Write(indata);
        }
    }
```

So, please help me to do this. This is the last step of my 3rd year industrial project. I am getting stuck here.

Comment: What have you tried? Aren't there any arduino guide around to get you started? What you are asking is easy, but it require several steps, what makes it a bit broad: read value of input at arduino, transfer it via serial port (you already there, but it's not yet protocol), read it on PC side, run code if certain input is set.

Comment: Arduino part is ok. When I check with it through serial monitor, it worked. Now I want to take it into Visual Studio application.

Comment: What do you send now? If you send that input value as single character (e.g. `'0'` for reset and `'1'` for set), then you should be able to receive it already and `if(indata[0] == '1') { ... }` should let you to run the method you want.

Comment: Yeah... that is what i want. But I can not use it. How can use serial port for this? Do I need to use console application? O r else how ??

Comment: That's what Sintr was asking/saying: You need a protocol. When the pin goes high, what does the arduino part send to serial port? Exactly this is what you need to read in C#. You can utilize the SerialPort class in Console, GUI-Apps and Service. Which Applicationtype you need is up to you. We cannot tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify the COM port the arduino is connected is the one used on your code? Also, what is the code you're running on the arduino? It would be helpful to have it shown, so that we better understand how you're approaching your issue.

I believe the easiest structure for you to use is the master-slave one.

I would suggest for you to handle the connection with the serial port using this function:

```
 Private Sub CommPortSetup()
   With mySerialPort
     .PortName = "COM10"
     .BaudRate = 38400
     .DataBits = 8
     .Parity = Parity.None
     .StopBits = StopBits.One
     .Handshake = Handshake.None
   End With
   Try
     mySerialPort.Open()
     Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
   End Try
 End Sub
```

This way, you'll handle the exception, if the connection is not successful. I don't see a way on your code to ascertain if connection was established.